# p:pickList and Omnifaces converter problem

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I have a problem with the primefaces p:pickList and in combination with the o:converter

I've setup already the ManagedBean and the JSF page

```
@ViewScoped
@Named
public class FormDesignerEditController implements Serializable {

    private DualListModel<FormComponentElement> formComponentElementList;
    private FormComponentElement selectedFormComponentElement;

    private List<FormComponentElement> targetAllList = new ArrayList<FormComponentElement>();
    private List<FormComponentElement> sourceList = new ArrayList<FormComponentElement>();
    private List<FormComponentElement> targetList = new ArrayList<FormComponentElement>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        formComponentElementList = new DualListModel<FormComponentElement>();

        // Source
        sourceList = new ArrayList<FormComponentElement>();
        sourceList = formDesignerService.createAvailableFormElements();

        // Target
        targetList = new ArrayList<FormComponentElement>();
        targetAllList = formDesignerService.createFormSettingsElements();

        // Set List
        formComponentElementList.setSource(targetList);
        formComponentElementList.setTarget(sourceList);

    }
```

And here the picklist: https://pastebin.com/XcAj3guj

Comment: Code should be IN the question, not a pastebin or the likes and in [mcve] flavour

Comment: Plus there is no actual question or problem description. Consider to study [ask] again.

Comment: Yes, but I got the information "your post is almost code"

Comment: This is becaus you did not add a description for expected vs. observed application behavior. You just claim there is a problem.